# Xib Size - seems to think its longer than it is

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is a bit of a strange one, but basically I am having a problem whereby the xib size of my initial view controller seems to be longer than the screen.

So, if you have an ad banner set to be on the bottom of the screen... If I run the app in simulator, it does not show on iPhone 3GS/4/4S devices, yet WILL show on the iPhone 5.

I have tried changing the xib size settings, I even created a new xib file, but the same problem is occuring which leads me to believe it is hardcoded somewhere, but I cannot think where to look for this.

It is basically like it thinks the bottom of the screen is about 30-50px more than what it actually is... Hence why the iPhone5 displays ok as it has the taller screen.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: its bcoz of the status bar.iphone reserve that space for status bar.

Comment: Hi Dilip, no the status bar is set to off... :(

Comment: do you have seted Status bar is initially hidden property to yes and set status bar to NONE in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its bcoz of the StatusBar. It reserve 20px of screen . You can remove this space by do change in `Status bar is initially hidden` in plist and set status bar to NONE in IB.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 5 has a taller screen. The most flexible way to lay out your xib is via AutoLayout. Here is a tutorial to get you started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2

Basically, you want the ad banner to be contrained to the bottom of the view.

Comment: I found the answer, it was my own silly fault - I had set another xib file to the wrong size so it was defaulting to that... But thank you and I will read that as well as I like the idea of auto layout! :)